# Extend two continuous functions into one continuous function.

Tags: general-topology

I'm having a rough time trying to prove this:

Let $X=A_1\cup A_2$ be a topological space; with $A_1,A_2$ closed non-empty sets in $X$. $A=A_1\cap A_2$.

If $f_1\colon A_1\rightarrow Y,\:f_2\colon A_2\rightarrow Y$ are two continuous functions s.t. $f_1|_{A}=f_2|_A$ then $\exists! \:f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ continuous function such that $f|_{A_1}=f_1,\:f|_{A_2}=f_2$.

**My Attempt:**  (Existence) Define $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ as $f(x)=\begin{cases}f_1(x)\quad \textrm{if } x\in A_1\\
f_2(x) \quad \textrm{if } x\in A_2-A_1 \end{cases}$.

(*) ***Every open set $B\subset Y$ can be expressed as $B=B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3$, where $B_1\subset f_1(A_1),\:B_2\subset f_2(A_2)-f_1(A_1),\:B_3\subset Y-(f_1(A_1)\cup f_2(A_2))$ are open.***

Then $f^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}(B_1)\cup f^{-1}(B_2)\cup f^{-1}(B_3)$ which is equivalent to $f^{-1}(B)=f_1^{-1}(B_1)\cup f_2^{-1}(B_2)\cup \emptyset$ which is union of open sets and therefore open.

I'm not sure of (*), maybe I'm assuming some sort of separation axiom and I'm not even sure why I need $A_1, A_2$ to be closed.

Comment: If you are not sure, it seems the reasoning has some gap. I would observe first that $f$ defined by your formula has the property: $f(x)=f_i(x)$ for $x\in A_i$. Then I would consider $B$ closed (easier since $A_i$ are closed) and $f^{-1}(B)=f_1^{-1}(B)\cup f_2^{-1}(B)$. You can try once again.

Answer (score 1):

(*) is not correct. Here is a  hint: Let $U$ be open in $Y$. Then $f_1^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A_1$ so we can write $f_1^{-1}(U)=A_1\cap V$ for some open set $V$ in $X$. Similarly, $f_2^{-1}(U)=A_2\cap W$ for some open set $W$ in $X$. Now verify that $f^{-1}(U)=V \cup W$ by noting that $X$ is the disjoint union of $A_1$ and $A_2\setminus A_1$.

Comment: As for why (*) is false in general: It requires that $B_1 = B\cap f_1(A_1)$. But there is no reason to believe that $f_1(A_1)$ is open, so there is no guarantee that $B_1$ will be open.